# How to assign sRGB color profile to an image using imagemagick

Tags: cmd, imagemagick

Through command line How to assign sRGB color profile to an image using imagemagick?

When I enter following in windows cmd

```
convert logo: -profile "sRGB.icc" logo.gif
```

I am getting following error:

```
convert.exe: unable to open image `sRGB.icc': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/26
41.
convert.exe: unable to open file `sRGB.icc': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/9
58.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that the file containing the color profile could not be found. You can [download the sRGB color profiles from the ICC](http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter). I'd use one of the version 2 profiles depending on your use case.